# Android Buttons in Fragments to not get triggered

Tags: android

Why do buttons in Fragments to not get triggered? I've already spent about 5 hours on this, but no onClick / onFocusListener will trigger

Edit: Code
So this Fragment(s) is on a ViewPager2 on my MainActivity and 
it just wont trigger any Callback Methods. I have also tried to but those onClick initializations everywhere

Fragment:

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var searchBinding: FragmentSearchBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    searchBinding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    interface OnSearch {
        fun onArticleSelected(position: Int)
    }


}



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    var test = activity?.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)

    searchBinding.searchBar.setOnFocusChangeListener{view, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus){
            if (test != null) {
                test.isVisible = false
            }
            Log.d("SearchFragment", "onFocus")
        }else{
            if (test != null) {
                test.isVisible = true
            }
        }

    }
}



}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.search.SearchFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:focusedByDefault="true"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/searchRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? fragment and xml

Comment: Here you go the code

Comment: There is no button in the Fragment code you provide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreateView(view, savedInstanceState)
    val binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    val view = binding.root
    // Set binding 
    return view;
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById(R.id.searchBar).setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->

    }
}
```

Comment: FragmentSearchBinding doesnt have a method inflate with those parameters and onViewCreated is called before onCreateView which would give a runtime error

Comment: Sorry I've made some typos. Updated

Comment: THANK YOU so much, the Log.d finally shows. Two questions: What was my mistake and what do you mean by //Set binding?

Comment: By ```set binding``` I mean that you can set here the variables your viewModel need if any ```binding.setVariable(BR.vm, mVm)```. Your mistake was that your fragment was not aware of your inflated view.